# How to delete a node with a Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is my Firebase Database structure:

```
project
|
|- Users
   |
   | - 00001
       |
       | - Likes
       |   |
       |   | - 00001
       |       |
       |       | - 'whatever':'whatever'
       |
       | - Unlikes
           |
           | - 00002
               |
               | - 'whatever':'whatever'
```

What I want is a DB triggered function that when the user adds to `Likes` the item with id `00002`, removes it automatically from `Unlikes`.

I am using JavaScript and this is the function I've got right now:

```
exports.likeItem = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}/Likes/{itemId}'.toString()).onCreate((like, context) => {
    return like.ref.parent.child('/Unlikes').once('value', (unlikes) => {
        unlikes.ref.child(context.params.itemId).set(null);
    });
});
```

The function is triggered correctly when the like is written, but doesn't remove the unlike.

The error is this:

```
'parent' of undefined at exports.likeItem.functions.database.ref.onCreate
```

Comment: From what you've shown here, the error message is suggesting that `like.ref` is undefined. Looks like you have some debugging to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you try to achieve, the following should do the trick.

```
exports.likeItem = functions.database
  .ref('/Users/{userId}/Likes/{itemId}')
  .onCreate((like, context) => {
    return like.ref.parent.parent
      .child('/Unlikes/' + context.params.itemId)
      .set(null);
  });
```

Note that you don't need to read anything with the `once()` method. Just define the correct reference to delete (with `like.ref.parent.parent.child(....)`) and set it to `null`.

Comment: @Sergio Are you sure of the proposed edit? With the current code if you write a like under 00004 it will delete the unlike under 00004. Isn't it what you are looking for?